# Adding multiple Preloads with conditions in GORM dynamically

Tags: go, go-gorm

I am trying to build a GORM statement with multiple preloads but I need to do it dynamically. I don't know how many preloads will get passed in to the db call.

```
type C struct {
    table string
    comp  string
    val   []any
}
func Querydb() {
   c := []C{{table: "table1", comp: "status IN ?", val: []any{"active", "pending"}}, {table: "table1", comp: "active = ?", val: true})

  DB := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})

  for i := range c {
    *DB = *DB.Preload(c[i].table, c[i].comp, c[i].val)
  }

  return DB.Debug().Omit(omit...).Clauses(clauses...).Find(&o).Error
}
```

So I need to loop through the slice c and add 2 preloads with conditions to my GORM statements but what I end up with is only the last preload being added. So in this example I want

```
DB.Debug().Omit(omit...).Preload("table1", "status IN ?", ["active", "pending"]).Preload("table1", "active = ?", true).Clauses(clauses...).Find(&o).Error
```

but what I end up with is

```
DB.Debug().Omit(omit...).Preload("table1", "active = ?", true).Clauses(clauses...).Find(&o).Error
```

Help please!

Comment: Removing both pointers (*) in your loop will make the chaining work.

Comment: Thanks but that is not the solution. The preloads do not get added. I still end up with just the last one that was in the slice